# UICollectionView reloadData issue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview, reloaddata

I don't know what is happening, but my UICollectionView is not reloading from another class automatically.

I have my UICollectionView in class1 and i am updating the data in it by calling a newArray from class2

```
    class1:

In view DidLoad

      UICollectionViewFlowLayout *aFlowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [aFlowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - 15, self.view.frame.size.height/3 - 30)];
    [aFlowLayout setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10,10,10,10)];
    [aFlowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];

    self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) collectionViewLayout:aFlowLayout];

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[searchedPersonsCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"SongCell"];
    [self.collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    self.collectionView.delegate = self;
    self.collectionView.dataSource=self;

    self.collectionView.scrollEnabled=YES;
    self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical=YES;
    [self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];

    [self.collectionView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];

-(void) reloadPersonsData:(NSMutableArray*)newArray
{
    NSLog(@"success");
    self.personsArray =newArray;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
        [self.collectionView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
        [self.collectionView setNeedsDisplay];
        [self.collectionView setNeedsLayout];

        [CATransaction flush];
//        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3 target:self.collectionView selector:@selector(reload) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

        //tried all the above
    });
}
```

when user ask for more persons, i access class2 by a protocol,

Now In Class 2:

I am Getting the new Array, passing it to the property array in class1(it is passed successfully and i checked from debug) then calling reloadPersonsData Function from class2 to  class1(the nslog "success" is printed so it is accessing the method.
But Nothing is happened!! numberOfItemsInSection or numberOfsection are not called!!and the uicollectionview is not updated

The weird thing, if i called the same method reloadPersonsData inside class1 from a button , i got the UiCollectionView updated!!! so what is wrong here?why it is not reloaded when calling it from another class
can anyone help me?

Thank you

Comment: @Jaeger i tried it now without any success, still not reloading:(

Comment: Check if the instance that class2 owned from class1 is the same as class1

Comment: @MustafaIbrahim yes it is the same, class2 is my main class, i am creating the instance of class1 in viewDidLoad of class2 just once , when user want more data in class1, i re-accessed my main class(class2) from a protocol, then calling the method in class1 without creating a new instance of the class1

Comment: Try to call reloaddata at viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear

Comment: @MustafaIbrahim this will not work in my case, because when user ask for more data, i just show a please wait dialog in class1 waiting the new array, so viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear will not be called when the new data is received because user is already in that page

Comment: @MustafaIbrahim sorry my bad!!! now i discovered that i am creating a new instance of class1 when calling the process of newData. Thank you so much for your help...make your reply as answer so i can consider it as answer..Thank you again:)

Comment: @MustafaIbrahim Thanks, i will be glad to make your reply as answer if you add it to answers section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Check if the instance that class2 owned from class1 is the same as class1

Good Luck